# Why does loop stop after exporting only one file?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to export Excel files to another folder as PDFs. The macro is stored in a separate .xlsm that I have open, and I directed the code to the folder with all the files that need to be PDFs.

The code only exports the first PDF in the folder. The error I got was that it could not operate in Page Break Mode, so I set it to normal mode for running the code but I still get the error.

Beyond that, it is reading the workbook that I have the macro stored in as a second active window. I ran the code to export to PDF on a single PDF and it worked as expected.

```
Option Explicit
Sub PPG_PDF_File()

'Below is used to make code run faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Dim wkbDest As Workbook
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Dim strExtension As String
    Dim wsA As Worksheet
    Dim strName As String
    Dim strName1 As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strPathFile As String
    Dim myFile As Variant
    
    Const strPath1 As String = "C:\Users\steve.argen\Documents\PPG\GW Sampling March 2020\PPG Balogna NUMBER 2\Final excel sheets\Test Macro Folder DNAPL Wells\"
    ChDir strPath1
    strExtension = Dir(strPath1 & "*.xls*")
    Do While strExtension <> ""
        Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath1 & strExtension)
        
        With wkbSource.Sheets("LowFlow GW front")
            ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
        
            On Error GoTo errHandler

            Set wkbSource = ActiveWorkbook
            Set wsA = ActiveSheet

            'get active workbook folder, if saved
            strPath = wkbSource.Path
            If strPath = "" Then
                strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
            End If
            strPath = strPath & "\"

            strName = wsA.Range("A1").Value _
              & " - " & wsA.Range("A2").Value _
              & " - " & wsA.Range("A3").Value

            'create default name for savng file
            strFile = wkbSource.Name & ".pdf"
            strFile = Replace(strFile, ".xlsx", "")
            strPathFile = "C:\Users\steve.argen\Documents\PPG\GW Sampling March 2020\PPG Balogna NUMBER 2\Final excel sheets\Final PDF\" & strFile

            'export to PDF in current folder
            wkbSource.Sheets(Array("LowFlow GW Front", "LowFlow GW Back")).Select
            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
              strPathFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
              IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
    
            Application.CutCopyMode = False 'If you ever need to copy a large amount of info, this will hide any warnings
            ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
        End With
        
        wkbSource.Close savechanges:=False
        
        strExtension = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
    exitHandler:
        Exit Sub
    errHandler:
        MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
        Resume exitHandler
```

it should be at the end of the routine and not in the middle of the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it! Would you possibly be able to explain why that broke it for my own knowledge moving forward?

Comment: The instructions I made you move should only be followed in case of an error.
The Exit Sub instruction (which causes the immediate exit from the procedure) is used to prevent the execution of the next MsgBox if the error has not occurred. The Resume statement and the exitHandler label are not needed in your case.